# php oop user added code via classes

Tags: php, oop

Sorry for the vague title but I'm not quite sure how to phrase this.

I want to create an application that is actually a framework for other developers to add code to in the form of classes (such as Prestashop). Is there already any frameworks out there that do this or has anyone any pointers on this idea?

eg. my base code covers authentication, templating etc. with user added classes providing specific functionality around specific data.

HTH

Thanks

Comment: The question makes no sense. You say you want to create something like Prestashop. Then you ask if there is something like that already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of the question was clear. But I'm assuming you can try [cakePHP](http://cakephp.org), which automatically creates add/edit/delete/show functionality if you have database schema in place

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure about a pre-existing framework, hence the vague question, but after research, cakePHP is perfect.